# Socket thread exits after disconnect

Tags: c#

I build a quick little script to take data from an app I created for my phone and put it in a textbox and it works perfectly with this code:

```
 private void workerVoid()
{
    string receivedDataString = null;
    listenSock.Listen(3);
    acceptedSock = listenSock.Accept();
    listenSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5665));


    while(shouldRun)
    {

        while (listenSock.SendBufferSize != 0)
        {
            Buffer = new byte[listenSock.SendBufferSize];
            int byteCount = acceptedSock.Receive(Buffer);

            byte[] byteFormatted = new byte[byteCount];

            for (int byteCounter = 0; byteCounter < byteCount; byteCounter++)
            {
                byteFormatted[byteCounter] = Buffer[byteCounter];
            }

            receivedDataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteFormatted);
            setTextDelegate sTD = new setTextDelegate(setText);
            reqFormVar.Invoke(sTD, new object[] { receivedDataString });

        }
    }


}
```

With workerVoid being a thread. Again this works perfectly however, when the device that is connected (my phone) disconnects, the thread stops running altogether (I get the thread .. has exited in visual studio) and my device is unable to connect after that, even though I have a while loop that should run forever.

How can I make it so my device can reconnect again after disconnecting without the thread exiting?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't include any code that operates on the shouldRun variable. Is it being set to false somewhere outside of the included code while your thread is iterating in the inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your code might throw an exception , causing the while loop to be ignored, to avoid this .
Surround your internal while loop in a try catch , and move deceleration inside the try catch block like so :

```
    var shouldRun = true;
    while(shouldRun)
    {
        try 
        {
              string receivedDataString = null;
              listenSock.Listen(3);
              acceptedSock = listenSock.Accept();
              listenSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5665));

             while (listenSock.SendBufferSize != 0)
             { 
                     ...
             }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I think I found what the problem is... If i put a messagebox under "receiveddatastring = " it works as expected and it only shows the messagebox when data has been received. However, when I disconnect, I get the disconnect message and then it constantly spews out empty messageboxes meaning that sendbuffersize is not 0 for some reason)

Comment: Because unless you changed it SendBufferSize is 8192, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendbuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx That is the buffer size, not how much data is available. You should be checking to see what `Receive` returns, that tells you how much data was read. `SendBufferSize` is essentially a "constant"